# android animation on different views

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I need to create a sequence of animations on several different textviews(all the textviews have the same animation as follows `

```
<alpha
    android:duration = "2000"
    android:fromAlpha = "0"
    android:toAlpha = "1"

    android:interpolator = "@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount = "infinite"
    />
<scale android:fromXScale="200%"
    android:fromYScale="200%"
    android:toXScale="100%"
    android:toYScale="100%"
    android:repeatCount = "infinite"
    android:interpolator = "@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX = "50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration = "2000" />
```

`

The animations on the views start at different times and the text views need to become visible when animation starts and invisible a few secs after animation ends) After this the entire sequence repeats after a pause. What would be the best way to achieve this? Would it be advisable to just create a gif file in adobe after effects and put it as background?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time gif is not a good idea , it's memory consuming and hard to modify or render right in different screen sizes

You can animate them programmatically instead of using xml

In my opinion it's a better approach because it lets you use properties like screen size and control flow to deal with different views animation